# Simple finding instances of matches in a list with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, for-loop

I want to find a word ('pair) in a list of sentences and add the frequency of each word to a count.  I am getting an assertion error but I don't understand where i'm going wrong. Is there a missing step?

```
def finding_instances(sentences, pair):
     counter = 0
     for sentence in sentences:
          words = sentence.split() 
     for words in sentences:
          if pair in words:
                counter += 1
          return counter

assert finding_instances(["welcome to the great parade", "good morning", "I enjoy Python", "Welcome in"], "Python") == 1
assert finding_instances(["I hate", "other languages", "I am", "Hello"], "Welcome") == 0
```

Comment: "... please *bear* with me..."

Comment: your `return` statement is inside the `for` loop. Move it to outside the `for` loop

Comment: Which assertion are you failing?  Have you made *any* attempt to find out the problem?

Comment: This way you're assigning words to a list of the words in the final sentence of sentences. Also, please clarify whether you want to count the number of times the word appears, or the number of times the substring appears. As in, do you want 'Thesaurus' to match when looking for 'The'?     You might also want to use the lower() method in case you want 'the' and 'The' to both be counted when checking for 'the'.

Answer (score 1):

You have almost completed!

```
def finding_instances(sentences, pair):
     counter = 0
     for sentence in sentences:
          words = sentence.split() 
          if pair in words:
                counter += 1
     return counter
```

Comment: Perhaps also use .lower() to make sure 'The' is counted when looking for 'the'.